# create docker image from rust workspace

Tags: docker, rust

Hi I have a cargo workspace and there are multiple projects on it. Now I want to dockerize it but I want every project in separate image. Is there a way to build entire workspace and create multiple images from that build?

right now im using a separate dockerfile to build every project like this:

this is the dockerfile for groups-service:

```
FROM rust:slim AS builder

RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
RUN apt update && apt install -y musl-tools musl-dev
RUN update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy entire workspace
COPY . .

RUN cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release


FROM alpine

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/groups-service ./


CMD [ "./groups-service" ]
```

and i have a dockerfile for every service.

but i want to have a single dockerfile that produces multiple images with different names like `service/groups` `service/report` `service/graph` so i can run `docker build .` once and have all services build.

because it takes a lot of time to build it right now and i want to reduce and simplify my work

Comment: *"Is there a way to build entire workspace"* - well there is `cargo build --all-targets`

Comment: @kmdreko i know but how can i create multiple images from that single build?

Comment: How do you make an image for a non-workspaced build? Just do that multiple times, no?

Comment: @kmdreko if i do that i have to have multiple dockerfiles each take lot of time to build. and its very slow

Comment: Please add important requirements like time limits to your question.

Comment: Please show us your Docker file. It is possible to build multiple images from a single file. In fact it is even recommended: one image for the build environment, then another for deployment where you only copy the required files from the first one. Nothing prevents you from building multiple deployment images from the same build image.

Comment: "*I want every project in separate image*" - Do you mean the *built executable* from each project? Are they binary or library crates? Where do you want the executable to end up? Should it be the `ENTRYPOINT` of the image?

Comment: What's the target architecture of your Dockerfiles? Are they cross-builds or for the host platform? Do you need to build your executables **inside** of docker or can you build them on the host system and then copy them into the docker file? If the latter, I don't see how creating a base `alpine` image and copying one executable into it would take a lot of time. You don't need to install Rust on the image to run the built executable. That's the beauty of compiled languages that don't require a runtime.

Comment: @Jmb Would you mind elaborating how to build multiple images from a single Dockerfile? Yes, there are multi-stage builds, but how can a `docker build .` create multiple tagged outputs?

Comment: I think @Jmb meant `docker build --target ` so you can create different images based on the stage name, with that you can have everything in the same Dockerfile, I'm not saying it's the best thing to do, just explaining.

Answer (score 2):

Simply build all your images from the same `Dockerfile`, e.g.:

```
FROM rust:slim AS builder

RUN rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
RUN apt update && apt install -y musl-tools musl-dev
RUN update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy entire workspace
COPY . .

RUN cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release


FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/groups-service ./
CMD [ "./groups-service" ]

FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/groups-report ./
CMD [ "./groups-report" ]
```

Then running `docker build` will build all the target images at once using the same `builder`. You can then set the image names with `docker tag`. In order to facilitate identification of the built images, you can add a [`LABEL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label) to each image:

```
...

FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/groups-service ./
CMD [ "./groups-service" ]
LABEL service=groups

FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/target/x86_64-unknown-linux-musl/release/groups-report ./
CMD [ "./groups-report" ]
LABEL service=report
```

Then use `docker image inspect --format='{{.Config.Labels}}'` or `docker image ls --filter=label=<key>=<value>` to identify the images. E.g.:

```
docker tag $(docker image ls --filter=dangling=true --filter=label=service=groups) service/groups
docker tag $(docker image ls --filter=dangling=true --filter=label=service=report) service/report
```

Comment: how can i tag each stage?

Comment: @mohammadjavad AFAIK you can't tag each stage from inside the `Dockerfile`, you need to call `docker tag` afterwards. You can however use [`LABEL`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#label) to add metadata to each image and `docker image inspect --format='{{.Config.Labels}}'` to see the labels attached to each image.

Comment: or `docker image ls --filter=label=<key>=<value>` to list images with a specific label.

Comment: The problem with this is that every time the code changes, a huge rebuild has to happen, might take multiple minutes. Is there a way to install each workspace member's dependencies, without needing to copy each one?